# How to check if an object is dictionary or not in swift 3?

Tags: swift, dictionary

Tried the 'is' keyword.

```
// Initialize the dictionary

let dict = ["name":"John", "surname":"Doe"]

// Check if 'dict' is a Dictionary

if dict is Dictionary {
    print("Yes, it's a Dictionary")
}
```

This will give an error saying "'is' is always true". 
I just want to check if an object is a dictionary. It can be with any key any value pairs.

[image]

The key is hashable and it is not accepting the Any keyword.

Comment: Why do you need to check this?

Comment: This is a sample code. I want to check if the object is a dictionary or array or anything else. @Abizern

Comment: Are you doing this from something like JSON parsing?

Comment: @Abizern Yes. .

Comment: You can try this `if dict is [String: Any] {
    print("Yes, it's a Dictionary")
}`

Comment: @RohitParsana the key can be an int. This code will not work always. Key is a Hashable instead of string. and I don't know what it is.

Comment: @abhi1992 If the dictionary comes from JSON parsing you **do** know that the keys are `String` (according to the JSON specification).

Comment: @abhi1992 in json data key should be string.

Comment: OK. I just wanted to generalise this. So there is no way it seems to check if an object is a dictionary or not you are saying? (without specifying the key values.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to check if an arbitrary object is a dictionary first of all you have to make the object unspecified:

```
let dict : Any = ["name":"John", "surname":"Doe"]
```

Now you can check if the object is a dictionary

```
if dict is Dictionary<AnyHashable,Any> {
    print("Yes, it's a Dictionary")
}
```

But this way is theoretical and only for learning purposes. Basically it's pretty silly to cast up a distinct to an unspecified type.

Comment: Thanks a lot @vadian. I didn't knew that there was a keyword called `AnyHashable` . It works.

Comment: Yes you can, but if you know that the object is more specific than `Any` tell the compiler that type. Don't fight the strong type system.

Comment: This is the correct answer. In practice, if the dictionary being checked will only have a concrete type then better to use that concrete type, however there are times when checking for a generic dictionary is valid/preferred - for example, when building a container that could accept a dictionary of any type.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to check if your object is Dictionary you can just do this:

```
if let dictionary = yourObject as? Dictionary{

    print("It is a Dictionary")

}
```

Comment: Worked for me like a charm. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a playground:

```
import UIKit

// Create a dictionary and an array to convert to and from JSON

let d = ["first": "Goodbye", "second": "Hello"]
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let dictData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: d, options: [])
let arrayData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: a, options: [])

// Now that we have set up our test data, lets see what we have

// First, some convenience definitions for the way JSON comes across.

typealias JSON = Any
typealias JSONDictionary = [String: JSON]
typealias JSONArray = [JSON]

// Lets see what we have

let dict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dictData, options: [])
let array = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: arrayData, options: [])

// testing functions

func isDictionary(_ object: JSON) -> Bool {
    return ((object as? JSONDictionary) != nil) ? true : false
}

func isArray(_ object: JSON) -> Bool {
    return ((object as? JSONArray) != nil) ? true : false
}


// The actual tests

isDictionary(dict) // true
isArray(dict)      // false

isDictionary(array)// false
isArray(array)     // true
```

JSON dictionaries arrays have specific types

Comment: Thanks @Abizern, I tried this . This is working fine. But you use a dictionary with <String:Any> format. This works with json parsing perfectly.  I wanted to check if the object is a dictionary or not. I didn't knew about the keyword 'AnyHashable'.

Comment: Dictionaries in Swift are typed. Objective-C dictionaries are `[AnyHashable: Any]`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using `if let` or `guard let` while parsing `JSON` objects

```
if let dict = jsonObject as? [AnyHashable:Any] {
     print("Yes, it's a Dictionary")
}

guard let dict = jsonObject as? [AnyHashable:Any] else {
     print("No, it's not a Dictionary")
     return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `is` operator to check type conformance.

Here's a little snippet where I check if it's a `Dictionary`or an `Array`

```
let dict = ["name":"John", "surname":"Doe"]
let array = [ "John", "Doe" ]

if dict is Dictionary<String, String>
{
    print("Yes, it's a Dictionary")
}
else
{
    print("No, It's other thing")
}

if array is Array<String>
{
    print("Yes, it's a Array")
}
else
{
    print("No, It's other thing")
}
```

Comment: can you please make dict as an array and run this code?

Comment: I have add an Array and check his type on the second `if` sentence @abhi1992

Comment: I did it. All the time http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58d3a9e8ff20be4ef473d2be @abhi1992 :-)

Comment: I forget the generic types in Dictionary definition. My fault. Now edited http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/58d3ab3bff20be4ef473d2bf